# Xquery ( XDMP-ARGTYPE error ) the expected type of a function input is different from the actual type

Tags: string, xquery, marklogic, type-conversion, untyped-variables

I'm trying to remove stop words from a text in MarkLogic 8 using this function :

```
declare function rec:remove-stop-words($string, $stop_words)  {  
  (: This is a recursive function. :)  
  if(not(empty($stop_words))) then  
    rec:remove-stop-words(  
      replace($string, $stop_words[1], '', 'i'),  
      (: This passes along the stop words after 
         the one just evaluated. :)  
      $stop_words[position() > 1]  
    )  
  else normalize-space($string)  
};
```

Here where I call it

```
for $r in /rec:Record
return
  rec:remove-stop-words(data($r/rec:Abstract), $stop_words}
```

It gives me the following error

> XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004)     fn:replace((xs:untypedAtomic("
> 			chapter
> 			utilized asymmetry of n..."), xs:untypedAtomic("
> 			book
> 			interrelationship between ...")), "a", "", "i") -- arg1 is not of type xs:string?

The function expects a `string` type but the actual type is `untypedAtomic`. I don't know what to do!
NOTE: (( The problem is not in the function because I've tried to use it for a different text and it worked well )).

I tried to  the code by converting `untypedAtomic` to `string` by:

```
return
  <info>{rec:remove-stop-words(data(xs:string($r/rec:Abstract)), $stop_words)}</info>
```

but I got this error:

> XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004)   fn:replace(("
> 			chapter
> 			utilized asymmetry of n...", "
> 			book
> 			interrelationship between ..."), "a", "", "i") -- arg1 is not of type xs:string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you iterate over `/rec:Record` and pass `$r/rec:Abstract` as input, at least one of your records is returning more than one `rec:Abstract`. The function signature for `rec:remove-stop-words` allows a sequence of values as input for `$string`, but the function body where you call `fn:replace` only handles input for a single value, so it throws an argument exception (given `xs:string+` and expecting `xs:string?`).

You can handle the sequence by iterating over `rec:Abstract` before you call the function:

```
for $r in /rec:Record
for $a in $r/rec:Abstract
return
rec:remove-stop-words($a, $stop_words)
```

If you use stricter function signatures, it can help avoid problems like this, or at least make them easier to debug. For example, if you define your function to only allow a single input for the first parameter:

```
rec:remove-stop-words($string as xs:string, $stop_words as xs:string*)
...
```

This will throw a similar exception when `$string` is passed a sequence, but higher up the call stack, which can help make these types of errors a little more obvious.

Comment: Easier to read and more concise to adjust the XPath and use only one FLWOR to address the rec:Abstract elements and get their computed string() value: `for $r in /rec:Record/rec:Abstract/string()`

Comment: @MadsHansen I agree in general but OP may have a reason for iterating over the other node. Often people post only a snippet or simplified example, and sometimes making assumptions like that will break their code, leading to more questions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are sending it a node and not a string. Try `$r/rec:Abstract/text()` or `$r/rec:Abstract/string()`

Comment: I tried and I've got this `XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004) fn:replace(("&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;", "&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;", "&#10;&#9;&#9;"), "a", "", "i") -- arg1 is not of type xs:string?`

Comment: Looks like there might be more than one Abstract. Try $r/rec:Abstract/text()[1]

Comment: If there is more than one you could use string-join to make it one

Comment: In most cases it's better to use `*/string()` instead of `*/text()`, so that it returns a single string for the selected element, and continues to work if that element happens to have mixed content.

Comment: Good point Mads. I just wanted to see if abstract had more than one element in the for clouse and it looks like it does. I would use xs:string in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code -

```
for $r in /rec:Record

return
rec:remove-stop-words(fn:string($r/rec:Abstract), $stop_words}
```